# Using Foreign Keys in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Although I have substancial experience in other programming languages, I am new to .NET/MVC, so I started by thoroughly following [THIS TUTORIAL](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) by Rick Anderson and I successfully created all the controllers and views I need for my project to work.

The next step was to associate the tables with foreign keys, which I did as following:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string postCode { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctor doctor { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute "doctor" is associating the table "Patient" with the table "Doctor". Everything is fine so far.

Now, I need to change the Create view, that the Entity Framework already created for me, so I can see all the available doctors on a Drop Down List and make my selection.

I've read dozens of forum threads and tried many solutions but didn't get it to work. I can display the dropdown and I can populate it with all the available doctors, but for some reason it won't validate.

This is how I pass the information about the doctors to the Create Patient view:

```
        var doctorsQuery = from doc in db.Doctors
                           orderby doc.name, doc.id
                           select new { doc.id, doc.name };

        var doctorsList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

        foreach (var item in doctorsQuery) {
            doctorsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(item.id, item.name));
        }

        ViewBag.doctorsList = doctorsList;
```

It is not working.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? What is the best solution here?

Comment: How do you mean "it won't validate"? How are you trying to validate it? What error are you seeing? Can you post the code where you're seeing the validation problem? The more information you provide, the more help people here can be.

Comment: What do you mean it won't validate?  That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense in this context.  Can you describe the behavior and how it differs from what you expect?

Comment: It shows "The value '5' is invalid". Could it be that he is expecting a Doctor and receiving an int?

Comment: 5 is the correct ID of the Doctor I selected on the dropdown list, so I really don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use

public virtual int DocID{ get; set; }  instead of

public virtual Doctor doctor { get; set; }

Comment: Nope, the result is the same :/

Comment: When I submit the Create Patient form.

Comment: What was your reason to use   public virtual Doctor doctor { get; set; } 
  instead of   public virtual  int DocID{ get; set; }

Comment: If I do use just the int, how can I do the association with the Doctor table? How can I say it is a foreign key? I had the tables generated automatically and, this way, everything was created just fine. Will this still work?

Comment: Well, I was assuming that the Id is the int field in the Doctor table which is a foreign key in the patient table. So when you load the dropbdown, you get the values from the db (doctor table). That is all you need. When you create a patient, then you pass this doctor Id as foreign key.

Comment: That is correct. The table Doctor has a field, called id, that is  foreign key in the Patient table. What I mean is: if I just use a DocID int in the Patient class, instead of using a whole Doctor object, the tables/classes won't be truly connected, right? I can see that it works, but isn't it bad behavior? That way, "doctor" is not a real foreign key, right? I hope I'm making myself clear.

Comment: You know, Doctor cannot be a foreign key but DocId will be a foreign key.  In your patient table, you need to have DocId which is a foreign key referring the id in the doctor table. So it would work perfectly.
In case some where in the patient code you need the doctor object, you can do like GetDoctorById and you will pass the DocId from the Patient and that should give you the doctor associated with the patient

Comment: I completely understand what you say and it makes sense. What I'm asking is: what differentiates that DocId int from a regular int that has absolutely nothing to do with the Doctor table? What makes it a foreign key, then?

Comment: Good Question, when you populate the dropdown, you have to bring the Ids from the database table and populate the dropdown....if you think the user might tamper with the data...you can do validation before you save it to the db